# Open Source Terminal Server For Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal-server

We are planning to give each of our users their own users account on Linux Terminal Server.

Users can log in to the Terminal Server with browser or with an application. I checked Ulteo Server (Virtual Open Desktop) - but are there any other Open Source Terminal Servers for Linux?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

instead of vnc which can be quite painfully slow over low-bandwidth connections check [nomachine nx](http://www.nomachine.com/) and [freenx](http://freenx.berlios.de/) - second one is fully open source of protocol/server from first one.

Comment: I have used nx before and it is a great replacement for X server or VNC.

Answer (score 3):

Any standard Linux installation is configured for remote use.  The traditional way of using it is with the X Window protocol, which requires X software on the client (e.g. as distributed with Cygwin).  An alternative is VNC.  Modern Linux distribution also offer VNC-based connections as a standard option.

Setting this up for all of your users requires some Linux/X knowledge.  I have no idea what Ulteo Server does, it may save a lot of configuration and troubleshooting effort.  Similar offerings may exist from other vendors.  But the basic capability of working remotely, with multiple users at a time, each with their own desktops on the same machine, is standard in Linux.

If you want to use the Remote Desktop Protocol built into Windows systems, you can do that on Linux: there are various clients (usually `rdesktop` or some shell around it) and to get a server you can install `xrdp` which builds an RDP server on top of a VNC server. I use both of these a lot to interconnect between Windows and Linux systems and even between Linux systems.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Linux Terminal Server Project [www.ltsp.org](http://www.ltsp.org/).

Comment: LTSP is generally used to get desktops onto a bunch of net-booting thin-clients.  I doubt it's that applicable in situations where the end user already has machine running a browser and other applications, as seems to be implied by the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Try LTSP, it has come a long way in recent years, and fairly easy to get clients connecting to it. Once the LTSP server is installed and running (note, which ever computer you end up using as the server, best to have dual nics, save you some headaches) you can change the bios setting of almost any desktop pc to boot to network and it will find and connect to the LTSP server automatically.

Answer (score 0):

While not fully open source, it's heavily based on OSS, is the [thinlinc](http://www.cendio.com/products/thinlinc/). The free version allows for up to 10 concurrent connections.